# Using Jquery to keep opacity of one div, reduce opacity of rest on hover

Tags: jquery, html, hover, opacity

I am a bit stuck with this one. Here is a basic outline of my setup:

```
<div id="shell">
  <div class="subelement">One</div>
  <div class="subelement">One</div>
  <div class="subelement">One</div>
  <div class="subelement">One</div>
</div>
```

I'm looking to, on the hover of .subelement, decrease the opacity of the remaining divs with subelement class. I am aware of how to use hover effects with jQuery, just don't know where to start when it comes to animating the remaining divs that are not being hovered over. Thanks any for suggestions.

**Update: Final Solution - http://jsfiddle.net/yqPFH/**

Comment: So, you are saying that if a user were to hover over on one div, the rest of the divs would fade, but the one hovered on one would not?

Comment: @Alex your updated solution misses out when the mouse is rolled between two elements :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien is correct.  This also stutters on hover states.  Answers provided by Drew Baker below that use `animate` aren't correct.  This isn't what `animate` is used for.  `fadeTo` is clearly the best option here.  Check my submitted answer for a smooth transition between hover states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this question already has an answer, an additional answer was provided that I tweaked and has since been deleted.  Here it is using jQuery and loses the hover state when nothing is hovered.  Easy.

http://jsfiddle.net/kKHt4/3/

```
$(".subelement").hover( function() {
    $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo("fast", 1.0);
});​​​​​
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks!  I provided a new one.  Works now.

Comment: @DrewBaker Then why does your code use `animate`?  The question doesn't call for this, nor needs it.  It's pointless to use it in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I would've used CSS instead

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw8yD/)

[**Demo With Animations**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw8yD/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="shell">
  <div class="subelement">One</div>
  <div class="subelement">One</div>
  <div class="subelement">One</div>
  <div class="subelement">One</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#shell:hover {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.subelement:hover {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the proper way to do this.  Only reason to use jQuery would be for animation.

Comment: @SethenMaleno Wait I'll give you an animation ;)

Comment: Keep in mind this only works on modern browsers that support CSS animations, and the question was specific about using jQuery.

Comment: @DrewBaker giving better alternatives is not bad :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#shell .subelement").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", 1).siblings().css("opacity", 0.6);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EV833/1

Comment: I like this, you only pass one function to `hover` rather than two and take advantage of method chaining.

Comment: Worked flawless. Appreciate the usage of siblings(), was hoping to learn something new. Thanks!

Comment: Hey dogbert just make sure the items doesn't get out of the opaque state even if you've not hovered any element

Comment: @Mr.Alien is right.  I have supplied an answer that takes this into account.

Answer (score 0):

Two-part question:

1) How do you keep only the first line with opacity:1 and rest at .5
2) Once selected or hovered, how do you keep the opacity:1, UNTIL you hover/select another line?